# Как получить полный тип объекта

Tags: java, рефлексия

Есть объект

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Я хочу получить тип этого объекта в таком виде

```
java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>
```

Но используя метод `.getClass`  я получаю тип в таком виде:

```
java.util.ArrayList
```

Каким образом можно получить тип оъекта в нужном для меня формате

Вот такой вариант кода у меня не сработал.

```
 private void invoke(String arg1, String arg2, Object dataObject) {
        Method[] methods = MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method m : methods) {
            if (m.getName().equals("invoke")) {
                Type[] methodTypes = m.getGenericParameterTypes();
                for (int i = 0; i < methodTypes.length; i++) {
                    Log.wtf(TAG, "Check class: " + methodTypes[i]);                        
                    if (methodTypes[i] instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                        ParameterizedType t = (ParameterizedType) methodTypes[i];
                        Class<?> cls = (Class<?>) t.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
                        Log.d(TAG, T.class.getName() + "<" + cls.getName() + ">");
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

В логах  будет это:

```
java.lang.String
java.lang.String
java.lang.Object
```

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1942680/6752984), правда это не совсем как вы хотите

Comment: здесь этот вариант не подходит, я уже видел!

Comment: А `list` пустой?

Comment: А это имеет значение?  нет, он не пустой, в нем есть объекты!

Comment: @KirillStoianov, Да, имеет. Смотрите ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если это поле конкретного класса, то вот так:

```
public class Main5 {
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Field stringListField = Main5.class.getDeclaredField("stringList");
        ParameterizedType stringListType = (ParameterizedType) stringListField.getGenericType();
        System.out.println(stringListType);//java.util.List<java.lang.String>

        Field integerListField = Main5.class.getDeclaredField("integerList");
        ParameterizedType integerListType = (ParameterizedType) integerListField.getGenericType();
        System.out.println(integerListType);//java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет, это не поле конкретного класса, этот  объект который передается как аргумент в метод.

Answer (score 1):

Если `list` не пустой, то задачу можно решить с помощью получения типа одного из объектов `list`:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add("Example");
System.out.println(arrayList.getClass().getName() + "<" + arrayList.get(0).getClass().getName() + ">");
```

---

**UPD.**
Более общий случай (список может быть пустым):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        someMethod(arrayList);
    }

    public static void someMethod(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        Method[] methods = Main.class.getDeclaredMethods();
        Type[] types = methods[1].getGenericParameterTypes();
        ParameterizedType pType = (ParameterizedType) types[0];
        Class<?> cls = (Class<?>) pType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        System.out.println(arrayList.getClass().getName() + "<" + cls.getName() + ">");
    }
}
```

где в строке

```
Type[] types = methods[1].getGenericParameterTypes();
```

`1` – это номер метода `someMethod(...)` в классе `Main`.

и в строке

```
ParameterizedType pType = (ParameterizedType) types[0];
```

`0` – это номер параметра `arrayList` метода `someMethod(...)`.

Comment: Хорошая попытка, но это скорее костыль, чем универсальное решение!

Comment: @KirillStoianov, С этим согласен, да.

Comment: @KirillStoianov, дополнил ответ.

Comment: мне наверное нужно было сразу выложить свой код, я как параметр принимаю не типизированый объект, мне нужно каким то способом получить тип из самого объекта, а не из типов аргументов метода.

Comment: А, то есть, есть метод `someMethod(Object obj)`, который Вы вызываете, например, `someMethod(new String("str"))`, и в самом методе Вы хотите узнать, объект какого типа был передан в метод (в данном случае `String`)?

Comment: да, и в случае когда я передаю туда ArrayList<String> object, вызвав object.getClass  я получу ArrayList , но хочу получить ArrayList<String>

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню, в джаве генерики существуют только при компиляции, а в байт-коде их нет, поэтому получить в рантайме тип с генерик-параметром скорее всего не удастся.

PS: Если ошибаюсь, напишите комментарий, удалю ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже написал `@Qwertiy` в `java` в рантайме невозможно получить тип параметризированной коллекции. Там хранятся объекты типа `Object`. `Type-safe` операций обеспечивается явным кастом к типу. Этот каст происходит на этапе компиляции.

Самое большое, что можно сделать, это определить тип для массива. Для них, почему то, стирания не происходит.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> Class<T> getType(T[] array) {
    return (Class<T>) array.getClass().getComponentType();
}
```