# instanceof для collection java

Tags: java, коллекции, generics

всем привет есть один метод, у которой входной параметр - `Collection<E> collection`

внутри метода хочу реализовать проверку на `instanceOf`, но увы условия не срабатывает.

как можно коллекцию проверить какой `ArrayList` - ом инстализирован?

```
private <E> void getTest(Collection<E> collection) {
        if (collection instanceof SBwCause){
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
    }
```

тут проверка не срабатывает на `List<SBwCause>` он не проверяет компилятор ругается

Comment: А коллекция пустая или нет?

Comment: не пустая когда вызываю передаю List<MyObject> пока этод метод только для MyObject срабатывает, я хочу его динамическим сделать что бы он для всех срабатывал но пока не могу какую коллекцию он про инсталирован

Comment: Хотите получить класс элементов коллекции? Попробуйте так `ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType)collection.getClass().getGenericSuperclass(); Class ec = (Class)pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];` ответ - `ec`. Напишите ответ, если получится.

Comment: Если такой вариант подходит, то можно определить метод как-то так `private <E> void getTest(Collection<E> collection, Class<E> clazz)`. В параметре `clazz` передаётся класс элементов коллекции. Вместо `instanceof` - `SBwCause.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)`

Comment: спасибо пробывал первый вариант getGenericSuperclas‌​s этот метод не наешл просто getSuperClass() вернул class java.util.AbstractList

Comment: Советую прочитать [раздел по generic-ам](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527754.do), что бы  появилось полное понимание, как они работают.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если коллекция `arrayList` не пустая, то получить тип ее элемента можно так:

```
Class cls = arrayList.get(0).getClass();
```

В более общем случае, требуемое можно получить, например, [таким образом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579725/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0).

В Вашем случае будет как-то примерно так:

```
private <E> void getTest(Collection<E> collection) {
    if (collection instanceof List){
        if (((List<E>) collection).get(0) instanceof SBwCause) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
    }
}
```